# Lucene .NET different results on different servers

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

We use Lucene .NET in a web application. We build an index from an SQL database, and then search it.

We have a situation that is baffling: same database on two servers, same code, same configuration (believe me, we've checked really thoroughly). BUT running identical searches gives wildly different numbers of documents returned (one produces a lot, the other not so).

We log the actual queries run against Lucene, and we have run those in the Lucene query analyser and we get the expected results on both servers. However, executing the query via our code gives a completely different result between servers.

We've even copied the index files between servers and we get the same result - the one server always gives a lot of results, the other doesn't.

We've checked the configuration of the two servers - both servers are Windows 2008 R2, 64 bit version, both set to the same locale etc.

We're baffled - any ideas greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you use Luke to check you index?  What version of Lucene.NET (3.0.3 RTM?)  Has the IndexWriter commited/flushed all the changes in both before comparing?

Comment: As I said in my post, we are using Luke to see what's going on and we get different results between our code and running the query directly in Luke. The index is fully flushed and committed in both cases - this is not new code, this has been installed on dozens of websites and has never given this problem before. It's V 2.9.1, BTW

Comment: Does Luke give the same answer between the servers? If so, the problem is outside of Lucene's code and index.

Comment: @eggheaddesign Where in your original post does it say you are using Luke??? I am not trying to be confrontational, but do you know what Luke is?  As Mark mentioned if you copied the index between two servers and are getting different results...its not Lucene...its something esle (caching, config pointing to wrong place, different version of an assembly/software, different version of ASP.NET/WCF etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Luke is a java application using the java-based analyzers available. I would expect that the result differ between Luke and Lucene.Net, especially if you use custom analyzers which differ from the java versions.

Also, remember that a `new TermQuery("f", "my value")` will produce a query that looks like "f:my value", but throwing that into Luke will really be parsed as "f:my default-field:value", i.e. a completely different search query.

I would start by verifying that you are using the correct analyzers, and that they are producing correct tokens. I would check for culture-sensitive things since they usually sneak up on you when you least expect it. (And cases where processes are executing under non-system locales, and where threads change their locales during execution.)